# Simple bufferedimage flickering when calling repaint

Tags: java, swing, repaint, flicker

I'm trying to create a webcam view with openCV but when I repaint the saved image it flickers and the images look half gray sometimes.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;

    public class Panel extends JPanel {

    BufferedImage img;
    public Panel() {
        super(true);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);


        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("webcam.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 640, 480, this);
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't read your image in your paintComponent() method. Read the image in your constructor.

Also, don't call repaint() from your paintComponent() method. If you need to continuously redraw, use a Thread or a Timer.

Edit: this might need some tweaking, but it's the basic approach I'm talking about:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Panel extends JPanel implements Runnable{

BufferedImage img;
public Panel() {
    super(true);
    new Thread(this).start();
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    if(img != null){
        synchronized(this){
            g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 640, 480, this);
        }
    }
}

public void run(){
    while(true){
        try {
            synchronized(this){
                img = ImageIO.read(new File("webcam.jpg"));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        repaint();

        try {
            Thread.sleep((long) (1000.0/30));
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: but then the image is only read once and it won't update. Another class (saveImage) saves the webcam image to webcam.jpg every 10millisecs

Comment: So I should make a thread to the constructor that reads the image and also repaints? and only draw image in paintcomponent?

Comment: Thanks! this must be the correct way to draw it. It still gives me some gray flickering but it could be that the problem is with opencv saving the photos. I'm probably using the API wrong since there's little documentation available for java

Comment: You might also be running into a situation where the file is being overwritten while you're loading it. You might want to use some kind of indexing system or something instead of writing/reading from the same file over and over again.

Comment: Yep, that was it. I changed from 1 file to a 3 file system and now it works clean. Thanks again!